# The place I live in

Tags: word-choice

Is "in" unnecessary in my sentence? My place refers to my hometown.

> "I love my country and the place I live in."

Comment: I would say "and the place where I live".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is commonly taught to native English speakers that ending a sentence with a preposition (for example "in") is incorrect. People still do it fairly regularly, though.

So that would mean the example sentence is incorrect.

It also sounds a bit awkward to a native English speaker. It would be more natural to say "the place where I live," though you could probably also be understood if you just said "the place I live."

Answer (score 1):

> ***"The Place I Live In"***

is a fairly commonly found phrase on the internet. Numerous English language Blogs have this phrase to introduce the locality where the blogger lives. However they are non native speakers and a prevalence of Russian Bloggers seem to use this phrase.

---

*Regarding its use I would totally agree with **"Mushroom"** it is non standard English.*

> "The Place where I live" or  "the place I live."

place noun (AREA) Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/place)

live; verb; (HAVE A HOME) Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/live)

> I'm looking for a place to live.